# Safari: VH units applied to parent element doesn't allow 100% height in child?

Tags: css, safari, viewport-units, safari7

I have a very simple situation, where I want to set a container element to `80vh` and then have the inner div to be 100% of that height. On Chrome this will render correctly, however on Safari, the inner element doesn't have 100% of the `80vh` height.

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
}

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Here is a fiddle showing this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/neilff/24hZQ/

On Chrome the element is blue, in Safari it is red. Is there a work around for this issue without applying `80vh` to the height of the `.inner` div?

Comment: Support is poor in Safari - http://caniuse.com/#search=vh Check the know issue at the bottom

Comment: I see issues with iOS7 Safari listed, but not desktop. The bug is listed for VH units, if I change this example to VW units, it again causes the same issue.

Comment: Ios is buggy for vh units. You can try viewport units buggyfill but I don't recommend it without any edit.

Comment: This bug is fixed in Safari 8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is a known bug with `vh` and `vw` in Safari. You can fix it by setting `height: inherit` on the inner element:

```
.inner {
    height: inherit;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/24hZQ/47/

Comment: God I love StackOverflow!

Comment: I found that `height: inherit; max-height: 100%` helps with browser compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to set `position: absolute;` to the `.inner` element.

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;
    position: relative;
}

.inner {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: `absolute` Doesn't work well. Doing so, creates double scroll, and layout gets blown out of proportion.

Comment: @misterManSam Sorry, but in my case i doesn't. I have list of items that are displayed as a grid. Setting both width, and height to 100% for inner element sets element to document % instead of parent. Here is a Gif for my current view https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/616034/vw-issue.gif

Comment: @SeifSallam - Can't see the gif. Can you show a basic example in a fiddle?

Comment: @SeifSallam In itself it shouldn't create any scroll, I need more information to know what's going on there. Do you have any padding applied to the `.container` element?

Comment: @pstenstrm No, but i'm using flexbox as my main outer container. The one that holds the whole grid.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using flexbox (tested in Safari 7.0.6, iOS 7 and iOS 8.0 simulator) -

http://jsfiddle.net/clintioo/zkmnomab/

```
.container {
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80vh;  
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.inner {
    -ms-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1.0;
    flex: 1;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Problem is, there is an outer-container that is above the current container, that is flex and doesn't have height. Container is like cell item. Which i sets the height for each cell. Finally inner takes 100% of the space of the parent, so that i can center elements inside.